# calling npm from webstorm commad line tool

Tags: windows, node.js, npm, webstorm

Im just starting with grunt in webstorm (on windows) and can't call npm (node plugin is installed and enabled, node.exe is in the system path).

npm init

what command line tool outputs:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3

Process finished with exit code 8
```

Thanks

Comment: are you using command line tools support plugin, or external tools? What does your tool configuration look like?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 9):

configure NPM with command line in Webstorm:

Webstorm 6 , you need to add command line support plugin  :

File > Setting > IDE Settings > Plugins > Command Line Tool Support

once you added to webstorm then

File > Settings > Project Settings > Command Line Tool Support

click '+' to add >
in popup window
Tool Path : C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
Alias: npm (or whatever you like)
visibility: select whatever you like
then > OK >
Apply > OK

in webstorm > Tools > Run Command > or (Coomand Line Tools Console)
type command in bottom bar: npm

you will see result something like

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd

Usage: npm

where  is one of:
    add-user, adduser, apihelp, author, bin, bugs, c, cache,
    completion, config, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, docs, edit,
    explore, faq, find, find-dupes, get, help, help-search,
    home, i, info, init, install, isntall, issues, la, link,
    list, ll, ln, login, ls, outdated, owner, pack, prefix,
    prune, publish, r, rb, rebuild, remove, repo, restart, rm,
    root, run-script, s, se, search, set, show, shrinkwrap,
    star, stars, start, stop, submodule, tag, test, tst, un,
    uninstall, unlink, unpublish, unstar, up, update, version,
    view, whoami

npm  -h     quick help on 
npm -l           display full usage info
npm faq          commonly asked questions
npm help   search for help on 
npm help npm     involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\kpatel.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm  --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@1.3.8 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm

Process finished with exit code 0 at 14:32:10.
Execution time: 794 ms.

Comment: This answer is old, but should be accepted. Saved me a lot of grief!